# How does trust work between an IDP and a SP in SAML v2.0?

Tags: go, saml-2.0, idp, trust

After reading a lot of documentation on the SAML protocol, I still don't understand how the trust between an IDP and a SP works.

I know that both the IDP and the SP must have a "Metadata" file containing an x509 certificate. To establish this trust, the IDP and SP must exchange these Metadata files.

But I don't understand how technically this works. According to my research, many IDPs offer to do this in a graphical way by uploading the metadata files. My final goal is to implement the SAML Protocol in Golang. That's why I would like to understand how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just standard PKI. IdP signs message using private key, SP verifies signature using public key, or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So there is no real exchange of metadata after all?

Comment: Yes there is. That's how the public keys (along with other settings) are exchanged. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) is a good starting point, but bear in mind that this is a BIG protocol. I hope that golang already has good XML canonicalization and XML signature libraries, because otherwise you're in for a treat.

Comment: Having written multiple partial SAML implementations before, I would consider a complete, secure, and from-scratch implementation to be a multi-year project, even with the XML/crypto stuff out of the way.

Comment: I have already read the Wikipedia documentation but I didn't find anythings about Metadata exchange. But thanks, I will look more precisely. 
Actually, SAML libraries already exist in golang so I think I'll use them as a basis. But I hadn't found anything about trust between IDP and SP. So I would like to try to implement it myself

Answer (score 0):

When you first set up a integration between SP and IdP, they exchange a metadata XMLs. The SP gets one from the IdP and the IdP get one from the SP.

It can be exchanged in many ways for example by email, or letting a SP upload it in a form or exposing your metadata on page on you service. The important thing is that SP and IdP get each others matadata and they trust they got it from the right person.

Metadata contain many things like endpoints and supported services, but also public keys. These keys are used to sign messages between the two.

When the SP send messages to the IdP, SP signs with its private key and the IdP verifies with the public key in the SP metadata. And vise versa, When the IdP sends something, it signs it with its private key and the SP verifies it with the public key in the IdP metadata. This way everyone can trust that the message came from the expected sender.

I have some other detail in a [blog post I wrote if you need it](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/matadata-exchange-trust/).

I also agree with @Robby Cornelissen. SAML is not simple, you have to do it right and consequences can be sever.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but that doesn't fully answer my question: let's say I develop a SP and an IDP in Golang. I create both of them a metadata file that I exchange manually. How can I do, technically speaking, to set up a trust? Is there a special request?

Comment: The trust is established by you exchanging the metadata files and configure you IdP and SP to use them. When you use them in subsequent communication you will use the keys in the metadata from the other to verify  that the messages came from them. Are you asking if there is a special request to exchange the metadata?

Comment: Ok thanks I'm beginning to understand. I already know how metadata can be exchange. My real question was : I want to develop a SP in Golang. For this I use any IDP. So I'll get its metadata file. Once I have the metadata of my SP and the metadata of the IDP I want to use locally, how can I concretely establish the trust?

Comment: Trust is typically established by you trusting that you got the IdP meta data from the correct source. To further trust that the metadata comes from the correct source, the metadat can be signed, but then ofcource you need to trust the key being used